# Problem with minimum and maximum inside function (Python)

Tags: python

everyone, I wrote this code and can't understand how to add minimum and maximum of sequence in return. I tried min(sequence) and other things. Nothing is working. Please, help.

```
MONTHS = 4
def main():
  precip = [0] * MONTHS
  print(func(precip))
  
def func(sequence):
  total = 0
  
  for count in sequence:
    count = int(input('Quantity: '))
    total += count
    average = total/len(sequence)
  return  total, average
  
main()
```

I found this code but i don't understand how to put it inside mine.

```
lst = [1, 0, 3, 6, -5, 7]
 
mins = lst[0]
for i in lst:
    if i < mins:
        mins = i
        
print(mins)
```

Comment: Sorry, but really need more info to be able to assist you. Please add sample input to your function with desired output.

Comment: Right now we add 4 amounts and function calculates sum and average of these four amounts. Additionally I need this function to define min and max of these four amounts and add to return.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to fill a list with user input one by one?
Your approach to filling the items in the array is not quite right, you need to write the values directly into the array and not to the element created by the for loop. This is probably why the other things didn't work.
If `sequence` is a list, then the inbuilt min max should work.

```py
def func(sequence):
  
  for i in range(len(sequence)):
    sequence[i] = (int(input('Quantity: ')))

  total = sum(sequence)
  average = total/len(sequence)
  seq_min = min(sequence)
  seq_max = max(sequence)
  return  total, average, seq_min, seq_max
```

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ВладимирДнепровский glad this helped you! Please don't forget to accept my answer as the solution!